# Text becomes invisible when stroke is added

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, core-text

I have next issue (sample code below):
I'm use `CATextLayer` and `NSAttributedString` to displaying stylized text. All work fine until I had added stroke to attributes. When I add stroke - text becomes invisible and in display I can see only stroke.
Please, I can't understand what happens, why I can't use both text and stroke?
Thanks.

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName: size:];
UIColor* strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha:1.f];
UIColor* foregroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha:1.f];
CTFontDescriptorRef fontDescriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithNameAndSize(...);
CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(...);

NSDictionary* attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            strokeWidth, kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName,
                            [strokeColor CGColor], kCTStrokeColorAttributeName,
                            ctFont, kCTFontAttributeName,
                            [foregroundColor CGColor], kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            nil];

NSAttributedString* attributedText = 
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];

CATextLayer* infoTextLayer = [[[CATextLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
infoTextLayer.string = attributedText;
...
infoTextLayer.frame = frame;
[self.layer addSublayer:infoTextLayer];
```

Comment: what colour is your stroke?

Comment: Foreground color and stroke color are different.

Comment: have a look at this link and see if you can find anything https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html

Comment: i think you can only use both with paths. if you could somehow convert your text into a path you'd be laughing.. by using CGFontRef see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGFont/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGFontRef

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your strokeWidth must be negative for text and stroke and positive for only stroke. From Apple Docs:

> *kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName*. This attribute, interpreted as a percentage of font point size, controls the text drawing mode: positive values effect drawing with stroke only; negative values are for stroke and fill.

Answer (score 0):

use kCGTextFillStroke - that does fill and stroke at the same time