# NSForegroundAttributeName not working. Text fill renders transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to make the fill for this text white, but the fill is transparent, and when I change the NSForegroundAttribureName, it has no effect below is my code.

```
 let textAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : 3.0,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()
]
```

In viewDidLoad()

```
textFieldTop.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

How do I make the fill for the font white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let textAttributes = [
NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -3.0,//Shpuld be in minus
NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()
]
```

[Text becomes invisible when stroke is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414387/text-becomes-invisible-when-stroke-is-added)

kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName. This attribute, interpreted as a percentage of font point size, controls the text drawing mode: positive values effect drawing with stroke only; negative values are for stroke and fill.